# Create multiple Databases in one query line

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is there any way to create multiple databases in a single line of a query?

Something like this:

```
$sql="CREATE DATABASE `db1` AND/,/./etc `db2` AND/,/./etc `db3`";
$mysql_query=($sql,$con);
```

Comment: mysql's prepared statements might work for this, but i'm not sure if you'd call it a single line.

Answer (score 8):

Other options would be to create a SQL file such as:

`/*myFile.sql*/
CREATE DATABASE db1;
CREATE DATABASE db2;`

Then run:

`mysql -u user -p < myFile.sql`

If you absolutely have to have it on a single console line you could do:

`mysql -u user -p -e "CREATE DATABASE db3; CREATE DATABASE db4; ..."`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but it should work only separated by semicolon ;
You could try

```
mysqli_multi_query
```

but you have to been connected to database with mysqli_connect not mysql_connect :(

Answer (score 0):

If PHPMyAdmin command or MySQL command -

```
CREATE DATABASE db01; CREATE DATABASE db02; CREATE DATABASE d03;CREATE DATABASE d04;
```

Create long script inside any text editor like notepad++, and copy, paste the Command in Console.
Then run command with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

##### you can create multiple databases using a scripting language like `Bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# List of database names to create
database_names=("db1" "db2" "db3")

# MySQL credentials
mysql_user="username"
mysql_password="password"

for db_name in "${database_names[@]}"; do
    mysql -u "$mysql_user" -p"$mysql_password" -e "CREATE DATABASE $db_name;"
done
```

- Save this script to a file (e.g., `create_databases.sh`)
- Make it executable using `chmod +x create_databases.sh`, and then run it with `./create_databases.sh`.